# Store large amounts of data from my Laravel website using SQLite3 database and React-Native App or similar

Tags: android, laravel, react-native, sqlite, electron

I am currently using indexdb to store data from my Laravel website but I am finding there are performance issues on mobile devices as I am storing large amounts of data. Can I create a React-Native app or similar with a SQLite3 database where I can store large amounts of data from my Laravel Website? If I can not do it with React Native I would appreciate any advice on whether this can be done using another method. Thank you in advance.

Kind Regards,
Jason.

Comment: Can you do it?  Sure.  But its non-trivial-  keeping data in sync between 2 different sources requires a lot of effort, and techniques you may not be familiar with.  Syncing is not part of SQLite.  And there's some mismatch between the data types as well-  indexdb seems to be a document store, sqlite is a relational store.  So not impossible, but a significant (weeks->months) worth of work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. At the moment we sync the existing indexeddb every x seconds. We need a relational db to add extra functionality to the project. Would you have any advice on how to achieve what I need to do? I have read about Electron which I believe does not currently support Android or iOS but looks very good. I have also read about Phonegap and Ionic. I could really do with a solution that will make an app for Windows as well but I am not sure how to achieve what I want and which platform to use as a web devleoper. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.